# Simplyfy HTML Table code using PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table, forms

I have a webpage (created from within PHP files) that needs to display a table that is 30 rows long and allows the user to enter values for each of the 30 rows and then press a button to let php process what they have entered.

Anyway instead of having to write out a normal HTML form with a table that has 30 rows I wonder if their is any way to create this table in PHP with much less code.

SO as it is it looks something like

```
<form name="createtable" action="?page=createtable" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th> Weight </th>
            <th> CBM Min </th>
            <th> CBM Max </th>
            <th> Min </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> 1000 </th>
            <th> 0.1 </th>
            <th> 2.3 </th>
            <th> <input type=text name=min1> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> 1500 </th>
            <th> 2.31 </th>
            <th> 3.5 </th>
            <th> <input type=text name=min2> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> 2000 </th>
            <th> 3.51 </th>
            <th> 4.6 </th>
            <th> <input type=text name=min3> </th>
        </tr>
            ..... + 27 more rows
    </table>
</form>
```

I am currently just writing out the complete table like above, the values for weight, cbm min and max are not increasing at a standard rate so a normal loop would not work I guess, could these values be put into an array perhaps? My php is very rusty

Comment: Figure out what part of the code is repeating (hint: tr with childs), and move that code into a loop. So for each row print a tr with content.

Comment: Just a note, `<th>` refers to a table header, after those first four you probably want `<td>`

Comment: Where do you get those values from? The ones that are betwen your `<th>` tags? (By the way, shouldn't those be `<td>` tags? Usually, you should only have one set of `<th>` tags -- all the rest of the rows should use `<td>` tags.)  If you get the values from a database, please let us know. Best if you show that code too.

Comment: This would be a good example of a need for a template system such as Smarty.

Comment: @evan.stoddard or just a php for-loop?

Comment: "much less code" than what? You haven't shown the code you're currently using, so how can we tell what you need to change it to? In general, creating tables usually involves a `for` or `while` loop that iterates over an array or database query results.

Comment: @Jordan unless he's filling the table dynamically...

Comment: thanks guys changed to td was a typo, @gibberish these are just hard set values

Comment: Actually looking through the values I have been given as they go on there is no set amount they increase by so I guess a loop would not work and I will just have to write it all out

Comment: Just because you can't automate everything doesn't mean you should hard code the entire thing..put the hard coded values in an array, and automate the rest.

Comment: you can create array of values and iterate over it using loop in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

```
/* this should contain all rows, a resultset from a database,
   or wherever you get the data from */
$rows = array(
    array(
      'weight' => 1000,
      'cbm_min' => 0.1,
      'cbm_max' => 2.3
    ),
    array(
      'weight' => 1500,
      'cbm_min' => 2.31,
      'cbm_max' => 3.5
    ),
    array(
      'weight' => 2000,
      'cbm_min' => 3.51,
      'cbm_max' => 4.6
    )
); 

?>
<form name="createtable" action="?page=createtable" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
      <th> Weight </th>
      <th> CBM Min </th>
      <th> CBM Max </th>
      <th> Min </th>
    </tr>
<?php
$i = 1; // I'll use this to increment the input text name
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  /* Everything happening inside this foreach will loop for
     as many records/rows that are in the $rows array. */
 ?>
    <tr>
      <th> <?= (float) $row['weight'] ?> </th>
      <th> <?= (float) $row['cbm_min'] ?> </th>
      <th> <?= (float) $row['cbm_max'] ?> </th>
      <th> <input type=text name="min<?= (float) $i ?>"> </th>
    </tr>
  <?php
  $i++;
}
?>
  </table>
</form>
<?php
// Continue executing PHP
```

Comment: Don't you need to `echo` those PHP statements? Or does the (float) somehow take care of that?

Comment: @Jordan: the `<?=` is a shorthand echo, don't worry, it's not affected by the removal of short php tags so it should be safe to use. Float is just to make sure we're printing numbers (XSS).

Comment: @JimL Gotcha, didn't know that it took care of the echo for you :P

Comment: @Jordan: it's great when building templates :)

Comment: @ZacPowell: Np, happy to see a question with a little more effort than "please code for me". Next time I'd add the data source as well, preferably with a var_dump of some test data. It just makes it easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You Could definitely do it using PHP

You would require a 2D array to have all the values which are to be shown in all your `<tr>` * `<th>` ie 30 * 3 in you case as the third column would contain the `<input>`

It would easy to find syntax for declaring an array and writing a for loop.

```
for($i=0;$i<30;$i++)
{
for($j=0;$j<4;$j++)
{
    echo "<td>array[$i][$j]</td>"
}
echo "<input>...</input>"
}
```